# Encoding in ruby utf-8 error

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I want to convert this string

```
"Nous travaillons \u00c3\u00a1 rendre"
```

to

`Nous travaillons à rendre`

but not able to do it. I tried `force_encoding("UTF-8")` method on string but that didn't work too. My output is always

```
"Nous travaillons Ã¡ rendre"
```

---

Only thing that seems to be working is if I manually replace `\u00` with `\x`

```
"Nous travaillons \xc3\xa1 rendre"
```

but `gsub` doesn't seems to be working on this `"Nous travaillons \u00c3\u00a1 rendre"`

i am using ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Obligatory: is there a good reason why you're using ruby `1.9.3`? This version is **old**, and no longer supported.

Comment: I am adding a fix to an Sinatra app and it's on 1.9.3

Comment: You might be able to convert the byte sequence 0xC3 0xA1 to `á`, but converting `á` to `à` is a spell checking issue, not an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode string and force encoding after this.

```
"Nous travaillons Ã¡ rendre".encode("Windows-1252").force_encoding("utf-8")
```

Result:

```
"Nous travaillons á rendre"
```

Comment: thanks but here is the error `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: U+2019 from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1
 from (irb):162:in `encode'
 from (irb):162`

Comment: Note: (1) The encoding may actually be `Windows-1252`, not `iso-8859-1`? And (2) it [looks to me](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) like the correct character **is** actually á, not à (??)

Comment: @SumeetMasih is that error from a *longer* input string? If so, can you track down a simple reproduction? if not, does my alternate encoding suggestion work? A clue as to the correct encoding may come from the *original data source* -- what is it? MS Word?

Comment: @TomLord yes, you're right. `Windows-1252` is true format. I updated the post.

Comment: @SumeetMasih I think the problem is that Ruby version is 1.9.3.

Comment: great, that works but the rest of the text is distorted `"Nous travaillons \u00c3\u00a0 rendre possible l’envoi de textos"` becomes `"Nous travaillons à rendre possible l\x92envoi de textos"` any workaround for that as well

Comment: @SumeetMasih I'm no expert, but it looks to me like you've somehow got *multiple encodings mixed up into a single string*??!! I don't know how to best deal with this... Maybe the issue was introduced earlier in your own codebase?? `\u00c3\u00a0` is Windows-1252; `’` is already UTF-8. So coercing the whole string encoding one way or the other seems to break something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: "Nous travaillons \u00E0 rendre"?

The character you want (Latin Small Letter A with grave) is a **single** unicode character.  That means if you are using \u, you want just **one** escape sequence, not two the way your question is.  You are mixing up the concept of Unicode code point (character) and UTF-8 encoding.

If you want to represent UTF-8 encoding in your string you should use **two** \x sequences... if you want to represent the encoded character itself, you should use **one** \u sequence.

It is only your incorrect use of \u that is making you have to resort to *force_encoding*